# $A$ is a field iff $A[t]$ is euclidean.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, euclidean-domain

I'm almost sure the question has already been asked but i don't know the english terminologies...

I have in my lecture that :

> $A$ a ring.
>
> $A$ is a field iff $A[t]$ is principal.

I'm anoyed because I think we can do better. It seems that $ \mathbb R [t] $ is euclidean. 
So, shoudln't be that theorem stated like that :

> $A$ is a field iff $A[t]$ is euclidean.

what do you think ?

I think that in my lectures, we are dealing with rings with a unity, commutative and integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $t$ is transcendence over $A$.

Stated as

> $A$ is a field iff $A[t]$ is Euclidean.

is weaker than

> $A$ is a field iff $A[t]$ is PID.

since we lost the ability to go $A[t]$ PID $\implies A$ a field.

I think the solution you are looking at is to have three equivalent statements

- $A$ is a field.
- $A[t]$ is Euclidean.
- $A[t]$ is principal.

Comment: so what you mean is that $A[t]$ is eucledean iff $A[t]$ is principal ? Because one direction is obvious (the direct one) and the other is implied by what you said.

Comment: So the end of your answer implies the three statement are equivalent right?

Comment: Yes, the three are equivalent.